# Nvidia drivers grayed-out in the Software & Updates: Unable to select

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, documentation

My system crashed and I had to re-install Ubuntu 22.04.
Now my Nvidia drivers grayed-out in the "Software & Updates" and I'm unable to select from the list of the other drivers as shown in the image below.

Could you please tell me how do I enable the drivers?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: I wonder what happens if you try to do it from a terminal window. Try `ubuntu-drivers list` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-470`.

Comment: I did something similar to what you suggeste:

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470

and this worked. Now the drivers are listed correctly with choices in the Software & Updates App.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to what @mikewhatever suggested:

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470

and this worked. Now the drivers are listed correctly with choices in the Software & Updates App.

Comment: This worked for me on upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10. In my case I did

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515